# split UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In the amazon iphone app home page there is a grouped table view that has two cells on one row. How can I recreate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect, that it is one cell, that shows different information. You can find a lot of informations about customizing UITableViewCells

- [iPhone Tutorial: Creating a custom Table View Cell](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284)
- [Customize that UIViewCell – Part 1: Using Interface Builder](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/customize-that-uiviewcell-part-1-using-interface-builder/)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your interface builder, click on your TableView and press command+1 to bring up the Table View Attributes. There on the first section Table View Style. Change it to "grouped".

Comment: i mean like in the twitter app

Comment: Twitter, Amazon, American museum natural history